# Alternative of Xamarin Component in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, components, nuget-package, xamarin-component

I recently open my one of the old Project. Which is use old Xamarin.component **barchart-1.1.2.1**. But as I open my Project is say

> **Time to Upgrade** 
>   We've detected that your solution is currently using Xamarin Components, which is no longer supported.Please remove
>   the used Components manually and reopen the solution.

I know it say that remove the Xamarin Component. But
I want the alternative of that Xamarin Component which is free to use and give the same functionality.

**Note And Research :**

> I know that all Xamarin Component now converted into Nuget Package but
>   I can't found barchart component on Nuget Package.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Not all components were converted to Nuget, it depends upon who published that original component and whether that 3rd-party is even still around (some components were free, some not, some open source, some not... )

Comment: @SushiHangover I have 3 Component in which 2 is convert and 1 barchart is not convert. So can i remove the remaining 2 one and check the result.

Comment: If you can not find it on Nuget.org (or some other 3rd-party site) and do not have the contact information of who originally published it and if they have an alternative, there is not much you can do other then remove it and search for a replacement (or code one yourself) and update your app to use that replacement.

Comment: You can copy the library dll from the components folder and manual reference it to your project if you cannot find it in Nuget. Then remove the barchart component and keep only the reference to the dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Resolve the Problem I just open the `.csproj` file

and **remove the all XamarinComponent** define in the csproj it will solve the Time to Upgrade error.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <XamarinComponentReference Include="Masonry">
      <Version>0.6.4.0</Version>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </XamarinComponentReference>
    <XamarinComponentReference Include="barchart">
      <Version>1.1.2.1</Version>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </XamarinComponentReference>
    <XamarinComponentReference Include="json.net">
      <Version>7.0.1</Version>
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </XamarinComponentReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20276935 - the answer was already given before the link; please be more careful when reviewing answers in the queue.

Comment: @TylerH Where is the Answer in the link. ?

Comment: Literally the first sentence answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use Alliance Charts in my project and they don't have the component on Nuget Package, so i just didn't remove it the package, everything works fine, the only bad thing is that the pop-up always appears when I open my project.
So just don't remove the package that you need, if not exists a component for it or until you find another component that do the same thing that your package does.